# get request in angular returning undefined on call to server hosted file

Tags: angularjs

Any reason this doesn't work?

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8383/api/login.php').respond(function (method, url, data, headers) {
     return authorized ? [200, customers] : [401];
  });
```

I know another way to do it, but would like to know why this doesn't work, as it seems to match the syntax in the docs.

safari: 'undefined is not a function'

chrome:  'err_empty_response'

Sincere thanks for the help... it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method respond as far as i know :-)

Either use `suceess with error`  or use `then`

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8383/api/login.php').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });


$http.get('http://localhost:8383/api/login.php')
  .then(function(result) {
    //USe result here
});
```

[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Its fine glad to help you :-)